# how to deploy a C# code to sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint

in SharePoint 2007 (moss)

i need to implement a button . a button to  create a custom action. this custom action registers a JavaScript file and a startup script. I have a C# code for this purpose.
i am not sure how to use the C# code. i was told the C# code just needs to be compiled into an assembly and deployed to the SharePoint server. however i dont quite know how can i do that.

( In case required, Reference to what i am trying to do is at this [url](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/03/05/select-multiple-list-items-in-sharepoint-feature.aspx) )

any help appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In article you see that "feature" file contains

```
ControlAssembly="SharePointSolutionPack, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4a7cd02bdf107f7a"
ControlClass="Motion10.SharePoint2007.SelectItemsAction"
```

That means the code goes inside class SelectItemsAction within Motion10.SharePoint2007 namespace.

SharePointSolutionPack is name of Dll file, which, when compiled, you copy to `C:\Windows\assembly`

However you must also copy feature defintion to (default location): `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES`

### A helpful resource for You

Anyway, what i wrote is not very helpful because i'm not going into details. [See this step-by-step example on creating sharepoint button](http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spcode/article.php/52271_3849011_1/Developing-SharePoint-Solutions-in-Visual-Studio-Using-WSPBuilder.htm) (exactly what you need) that uses Visual Studio extension that helps you develop features and deploy them (without copy-pasting i meantioned above). (You'll learn how to create features with that article)

It is important to learn about sharepoint features, because before i understood how to create features, it was hard to do anything in sharepoint (couldn't understand sharepoint articles, when i saw code, all the time question pops up - where do i put that code?).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice walkthrough. Hope it will help you out mate.

[Deploy MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583149(office.11).aspx)

[Walkthrough: Creating a Webpart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452873.aspx)